# Why the String length is 6?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

```
NSString *str = nil;
NSLog(@"str = %@",str);
NSLog(@"str.length = %u",str.length);

NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
NSLog(@"str2 = %@",str2);
NSLog(@"str2.length = %u",str2.length);
```

The NSLog imformations are:

```
str = (null)
str.length = 0
str2 = (null)
str2.length = 6
```

str2.length= 6 make me confused,why?

Comment: You don't understand why "(null)" is 6 characters??

Comment: Because str2 is a string "(null)", str is nil

Answer (score 5):

This looks confusing indeed. The reason for this, however, is simple: when you call `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];` and pass `nil` for `str`, you get a string that spells literally

```
"(null)"
```

Quotes are for clarity, they are not part of the string. As you can see, the string has exactly six characters.